# Overcoming Python's limitations regarding instance methods

Tags: python, oop, copy, instance-method

It seems that Python has some limitations regarding instance methods.

1. Instance methods can't be copied.
2. Instance methods can't be pickled.

This is problematic for me, because I work on a very object-oriented [project](http://garlicsim.org) in which I reference instance methods, and there's use of both deepcopying and pickling. The pickling thing is done mostly by the multiprocessing mechanism.

What would be a good way to solve this? I did some ugly workaround to the copying issue, but 
I'm looking for a nicer solution to both problems.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Update:**

My use case:  I have a tiny event system. Each event has an `.action` attribute that points to a function it's supposed to trigger, and sometimes that function is an instance method of some object.

Comment: Usually, we provide the code in all locations in which we're working and merely move a representation of the state around.  Representation State Transfer is more common and simpler.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: S.Lott, you clearly have more experience with this issue, but please explain it to me in a more dumbed-down way, what exactly are you suggesting, how does it relate, what is "Representation State Transfer", etc.

Comment: You're saying "I want to pickle instance methods", but you're not saying why. It would help us to know what problem you're trying to solve, since there may be a more Pythonic way to do it. It sounds a bit like you're thinking in Ruby...

Comment: Jonathan: I have a tiny event system. Each event has an `.action` attribute that points to a function it's supposed to trigger, and sometimes that function is an instance method of some object.

Comment: @cool-RR: Please do not comment on your own question.  It's your question.  You own it.  Please update the question with additional information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be able to do this using [`copy_reg.pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy_reg.html#copy_reg.pickle). In Python 2.6:

```
import copy_reg
import types

def reduce_method(m):
    return (getattr, (m.__self__, m.__func__.__name__))

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, reduce_method)
```

This does not store the *code* of the method, just its name; but that will work correctly in the common case.

This makes both pickling and copying work!

Comment: Good idea, I think it might be the cleanest solution. Do you have any idea for the other problem, copying? Also, did anyone already implement a `copy_reg` solution that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

REST - Representation State Transfer.  Just send state, not methods.

To transfer an object X from A to B, we do this.

1. A encode the state of X in some
   handy, easy-to-parse notation.  JSON
   is popular.
2. A sends the JSON text to B.
3. B decodes the state of X form JSON
   notation, reconstructing X.

B must have the class definitions for X's class for this to work.  B must have all functions and other class definitions on which X's class depends.  In short, both A 
and B have all the definitions.  Only a representation of the object's state gets moved 
around.

See any article on REST.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm

Comment: Can you please explain how this methodology relates to my problem with the event system?

Comment: This is a "you're doing it wrong" answer. This view is that `pickle` is maybe a little *too* convenient in Python; it's really better to exchange Plain Old Data (as opposed to object graphs) because it results in simpler systems that are saner to reason about. There's something in that, but if it's helpful to you at all it'll be helpful in a long-term way.

Answer (score -3):

pickle the instance and then access the method after unpickling it. Pickling a method of an instance doesn't make sense because it relies on the instance. If it doesn't, then write it as an independent function.

```
import pickle

class A:
     def f(self):
         print 'hi'

x = A()
f = open('tmp', 'w')
r = pickle.dump(x, f)
f.close()
f = open('tmp', 'r')
pickled_x = pickle.load(f)
pickled_x.f()
```

Comment: A() isn't an instance method.

Comment: You pickled the object, not the instance method. Try pickling an instance method directly.

Comment: pickle the instance and then access the method after unpickling it. 

Pickling a method of an instance doesn't make sense because it relies on the instance. If it doesn't, then write it as an independent function.