# serialize instances of scipy rv_continuous and rv_discrete subclasses

Tags: python, serialization, scipy, pickle

I am using the distribution classes in `scipy.stats.distributions` and need to serialize instances for storage and transfer. These are quite complex objects, and they don't pickle. I am trying to develop a mixin class that makes objects pickle-able, so that I can work with remixed subclasses that otherwise behave just like the objects from scipy.stats. The more I investigate the problem, the more confused I become, and I wonder if I am missing an obvious way to do this.

I have read a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798450/) on how to pickle instance methods, but this is only part of the overall solution that I need and may not even be necessary. I have experimented with writing pickle support functions that closely follow the `__init__` method and serialize the object as arguments to `__init__`, but this seems brittle, especially when subclasses can define arbitrary subclass-specific behavior in `__init__`.

Does someone have an elegant solution to share?

**Update:** I found a [Python bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue558238) with an example of registering pickle support functions with the `copy_reg` module to pickle instance methods. For my case, the instance method attributes were the only blockers. However, I would still like to know if there is a way to use a mixin class to solve this problem, because `copy_reg` has global effects which may not be desireable in all situations.