# Free memory for multiprocessing pickled methods

Tags: python, methods, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm using the first answer to this question

[Overcoming Python's limitations regarding instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798450/overcoming-pythons-limitations-regarding-instance-methods)

to be able to use multiprocess module on methods of one of my own classes.

As an example let's say that I have the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def myParallelFunc(my_list, a, b, inst):
    # do something
    return True

def myFunc:
    # instantiate custom class
    my_instance = MyObject()

    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(functools.partial(myParallelFunc, a=5, b=7, inst=my_instance), my_list)

    # SOLUTION!!!
    pool.close()
```

Now I have another program that calls myFunc let's say 100 times.
Every time I call myFunc some memory is occupied and never freed.
Is there a way to explicitly free it?

Comment: How do you know it's never freed?  Python memory management should take care of things for you.

Comment: I monitor it with "top" and it is released only at the end, when the program exits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new Pool at every call to myFunc. It is not deleted automatically when myFunc exits, because the child processes and related threads remain.

Create a Pool, keep it around for those 100 calls, then .close it