# Storing a process object in multiprocessing Manager.dict()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have created this sample program to generalize the issue i am facing

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

def f (_print):
    print _print
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    dict = manager.dict()
    dict['process_obj'] = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args= ('hello function', ))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

So how do I store a process object in multiprocessing Manager.dict()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about getting this error:

```
hello function
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "mp2.py", line 8, in f
    dict['process_obj'] = multiprocessing.current_process()
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

(it's generally a good idea to include "what I got" and "what I expected to get instead" in the question).

The fundamental problem here is that `multiprocessing.current_process()` returns an instance method.  Instance methods don't pickle properly, and `multiprocessing` has to save (pickle) and load (unpickle) shared data items to communicate their values from one process to another.  See, e.g., [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma) and [Overcoming Python's limitations regarding instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798450/overcoming-pythons-limitations-regarding-instance-methods).  Note in particular one of the answers in the second: it might be better to figure out some state to send/share, rather than an entire instance.  For instance, if the `ident` of a process suffices, you can do this:

```
    dict['process_obj'] = multiprocessing.current_process().ident
```

which works fine.